# Errors while connecting to the remote server using HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#

My Client project running in one server & API running in another server.
I got the following issue either of first time or some concurrent API request.
but sometimes getting a result as expected. some time not.below error got.
unable to find what exactly issue. can help me.

> My Code:

```
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
request.Proxy = null;
Stream dataStream;
HttpWebResponse response;
StreamReader reader;
var cred = new CredentialCache();
request.Method = "POST";
string postData = "type=1&someparameter=2";
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 4;
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
request.KeepAlive = false;
request.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
cred.Add(new Uri(URL), "Basic", new NetworkCredential(Username, Password));
request.Credentials = cred;
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.PreAuthenticate = true;
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();
response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
retmsg = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
dataStream.Close();
response.Close();
```

> The error I get:

```
<LogEntry Date="" Severity="Exception" Source="xxxxxxxx" ThreadId="87">
    <Exception Type="System.Net.WebException" Source="xxxxxxxx">
        <Message>Unable to connect to the remote server</Message>
        <Exception Type="System.Net.Sockets.SocketException" Source="System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect">
            <Message>
                    A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, 
                    or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond IPAddress:port
            </Message>
            <StackTrace>
                    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
                    at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket&amp; socket,
                    IPAddress&amp; address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception&amp; exception)
            </StackTrace>
        </Exception>
    </Exception>
</LogEntry>
```

Comment: Disregarding your complete lack of `using` statements and initialised variables. The fact that this is intermittent and the error message `A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time` kind of says it all. Most likely you are having some sort of environmental problems (somewhere in between you and them) which does not include your code

Comment: Op, take comment above this seriously, i almost got heart attack watching lack of using statements.